# Is it possible to make changes to a line written to STDOUT in shell?

Tags: shell, stdout

Is it possible to make changes to a line written to STDOUT in shell, similar to the way many programs such as *scp* do?

The point would be to allow me to essentially have a ticker, or a monitor of some sort, without it scrolling all over the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the terminal with control characters and [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). For example `\b` returns the cursor one position back, and `\r` returns it to the beginning of the line. This can be used to make a simple ticker:

```
for i in $(seq 10)
do
    echo -en "Progress... $i\r"    # -e is needed to interpret escape codes
    sleep 1
done
echo -e "\nDone."
```

With [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) you can do even more, like clear part of the screen, jump to any position you want, and change the output color.

Comment: `printf` is also useful in place of `echo -e`

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks, `echo -e` wasn't working right on my box!

Comment: I think you took inspiration from my answer (regarding the example only), am I wrong?

Comment: @Ben I hadn't seen your answer when I decided the point would be made clearer by a loop... It's just that there just aren't that many ways to make a simple loop in shell...

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the last printed line by printing the `\r` character.

For instance this:

```
for i in `seq 1 10`; do
   echo -n $i;
   sleep 1;
   echo -n -e "\r" ;
done
```

Will print `1` then update it with `2` and so on until 10.

Comment: you don't need all those line continuation chars.

Comment: You don't need all those semicolons either…

Answer (score 0):

You can do modify the output of stdout using another program in a pipeline.  When you run the program you use | to pipe the input into the next program.  The next program can do whatever it wants with the output.  A general purpose program for modifying the output of a program is sed, or you could write something yourself that modifies the data from the previous program.

A shell program would be something like:

```
while read line; do
    # do something with $line and output the results
done
```

so you can just:

```
 the_original_program | the_above_program
```